# Нет фиксации блока div absolute

Tags: css

Столкнулся с проблемой при верстке.

Необходимо зафиксировать 
`<div class="andrew_top_nav_absolute">`, чтобы при изменении ширины браузера оставался на месте пробовал играться с `left: right:` результата не дало.

Подскажите в какую сторону двигаться?

```css
.andrew_top_nav {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.andrew_top_nav_absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 1356px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="andrew_top_nav">
  <div class="andrew_top_nav_absolute">
    <a href="">Link1</a>
    <a href="">Link2</a>
    <a href="">Link3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: оставался на каком месте? где именно Вы его хотите зафиксировать?

Comment: position:fixed;

Comment: если применить fixed то при прокрутке вниз вверх блок будет зафиксирован.
Мне необходимо что бы элемент не менял свою позицию при изменении ширины браузера
не плавал: влево, вправо

Comment: @humster_spb
зафиксировать по горизонтали по центру страницы, что бы при изменении ширины окна браузера позиция не менялась....

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
   .andrew_top_nav {
        height: 35px;
        width: 1638px;
        margin:0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .andrew_top_nav_absolute {
        height: 35px;
        width:1356px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

при фиксации абсолют нужно указать один из параметров top, left, right, bottom

например если я хочу зафиксировать блок наверху экрана слева нужно указать:
top: 0;
left: 0;

если хочу зафиксировать на 20 пикселей левее от правой стороны экрана :
right: 20px;

поиграйтесь и поймете как это работает